# bind error to embedded form field in symfony2's controller

Tags: forms, symfony, error-handling

Using Symfony2.3.4

As the title quite explains it I need to bind an error message to an embedded form field and preferably in the controller. I'm thinking maybe similar to how I do it with single forms:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
//....
public function createAction(){
//.....
$postData = current($request->request->all());

if ($postData['field_name'] == '') {
            $error = new FormError("Write some stuff in here");
            $form->get('field_name')->addError($error);
        }
//.....
}
```

or maybe it's got to be done differently, either way I need help,

thank$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, that you are trying to display a message when a form field does not contain any value. You can do this easily in your form class, like this:

```
buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('field_name', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Field label',
        'required' => true,
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Write some stuff in here.'))
         ),
    ));
}
```

If you need to inject some other kind of constraint to your form which is not part of Symfony2 framework, you can [create your own validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).

If you want to add some options to your form in controller, it can be done in the method where you create the form by setting your own options:

```
class YourController {
    public function createForm(YourEntity $yourEntity){
        $form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType(), $yourFormType, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('your_action_name', 
            array('your_custom_option_key' => 'Your custom option value')),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        return $form;
    }

    // Rest of code omitted.
}
```

After that you need to add an option in `setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)` method, in your form class, like this:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'your_custom_option_key' => '',
    ));
}
```

And then access it in `buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)` method, like this:

```
buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $options['your_custom_option_key']; // Access content of your option

    // The rest of code omitted.
}
```